# Operate on pattern between and including two matches

Tags: vim

I'd like to operate on all text between two delimiting patterns, including the delimiters, and including multiple occurrences of the delimiters.

For example: `:g/pattern1/,/pattern2/s/\n/^A` will replace newlines with `^A` on all lines between and including `pattern1` and `pattern2`. However, if pattern2 appears more than 3 times, it will only match up to the second occurrence after pattern1, and I'm not sure why. I'd like to extend that to match all occurrences of pattern2 up to but excluding the next occurrence of pattern1.

Example data:

```
pattern1
text
more text
pattern2

pattern1
text
pattern2
pattern2

pattern1
text
pattern2
pattern2
pattern2
```

Desired end state:

```
pattern1^Atext^Amore text^Apattern2^A
pattern1^Atext^Apattern2^Apattern2^A
pattern1^Atext^Apattern2^Apattern2^Apattern2^A
```

Actual end state:

```
pattern1^Atext^Amore text^Apattern2^A
pattern1^Atext^Apattern2^Apattern2

pattern1^Atext^Apattern2^Apattern2
pattern2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that `pattern1` isn't repeated within a group, it's far easier to search backwards from `pattern2` to `pattern1`

```
g/pattern2/?pattern1?,.s/\n/^A
```

As for your question of matching up only to the second occurrence after `pattern1`, that is not what actually happens.

For each match of `pattern1`

- the first `pattern2` is matched
- the `eol` of each item from the group gets changed to `^A`

There is never an `eol` from a second `pattern2` changed. 
From this

```
pattern2
pattern2
```

only the first pattern2 gets changed but that results in

```
pattern2^Apattern2
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to remove the duplicate 'pattern2' strings and then apply the (pattern1, pattern2) range restricted substitution:

```
:%s/\(pattern2\)\(\n\1\)\+/\1/ | g/pattern1/,/pattern2/s/\n/^A
```